# ModelState validation not working with DropDownList and nested objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

In our application we have a Domain layer which contains classes with DataAnnotations for Validation.

We are using these classes in our models in our ASP.NET MVC ui layer.

For example:

Domain Layer:

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    // ... some model logic abreviated
}

public class Supplier 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    // ... some model logic abreviated
}
```

In our ASP.NET MVC presentation layer:

```
public class SupplierEditModel
{
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Company> Company { get; set; }
    public int SelectedCompany { get; set; }

    // ... some model logic abreviated
}
```

In this case we have a page with a DropDownList of companies. The list is binding  like so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCompany, new SelectList(Model.Companies, "Id", "Description", Model.SelectedCompany))
```

Our problem is on the POST method of our controller, when we are checking ModelState.IsValid, the model is not valid because Supplier.Company is null. We can then get the company using the SelectedCompany but our problem is that this means we can't do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(SupplierEditModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.CreateSupplier(_supplierService);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Create");
}
```

We would like to use validation before creating the supplier.

Comment: You can remove `Company` from `ModelState` before checking for `IsValid`: `ModelState.Remove("Supplier.Company")`.

Comment: @Zabavsky You should submit this as an answer, I will upvote it and could accept it (depending on other answers).

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that you have (at least) two options:

You could flatten your view model and omit `Supplier.Company` if it is not needed in your view.

```
public class SupplierEditModel
{
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Company> Company { get; set; }
    public int SelectedCompany { get; set; }

    // ... some model logic abreviated
}
```

(Note: your data annotations should be on the view model, not the domain model.)

or

You could clear the `ModelState` error before checking the `IsValid` property

```
ModelState.Remove(string key, ModelState);
```

Best practice here would probably be using the flattened model, for two reasons.  One, it's generally a good practice to only send the view what it needs and nothing more.  If the view isn't doing anything with the Supplier.Company, then it shouldn't be part of the model. Two, using the ModelState.Remove method, while effective, may be viewed by some as being a little kludgy.  You may get your chops busted a bit in a code review;)

Answer (score 2):

You can remove `Company` from `ModelState` before checking for `IsValid`: `ModelState.Remove("Supplier.Company")`

Answer (score -1):

```
   public class OrderViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Customer")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select customer.", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel> Customers { get; set; }
    }


   public class CustomerViewModel
    {
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    }

     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CustomerName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CustomerName, new SelectList(Model.Customers, "CustomerId", "CompanyName"), "- Please Select -", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's better to explain the answer then give only the code.